# iOS-only issue: HTML with <script> loaded via AJAX won't execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, ajax

What the following code is supposed to do is load in `innerStuff.html` within the `content-container` div. Then, another script in `innerStuff.html` called `submit_entry()` is used to submit `innerStuff.html`'s form.

**What I got**: When the button's clicked, `submit_entry()` in `innerStuff.html` (loaded via AJAX) will execute on any browser , **except those on iOS**.

**As far as I know, this is the only issue that I can encounter on iOS. When using any other platform, the function works.**

`index.html`

```
//Normal HTML stuff above
<div id="content-container"></div>
//Normal HTML stuff
<script>
getStuff = function(filename){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://website.com/ajax/",
        data: {
            'name': filename
        },
        success : function(data){
            $('#content-container').animate({opacity: '0'}, 250, function(){$('#content-container').html(data);});
            $('#content-container').animate({opacity: '1'}, 250);
        }
    });
};

getStuff('innerStuff'); //Gets innerStuff.html
</script>
```

`innerStuff.html`

```
<div id="form-container">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form">
        //Normal form stuff here (>5 elements)
    </form>
    <button id="submit-btn" onclick="javascript:submit_form();">Submit</button>
    <script>
        form['2'].value = "Something"; //The default value (the form has >5 elements, and is the only form on the website)
        submit_form = function() {
            alert("Submitting form. Please wait...");
            $.ajax({
                url : "https://website.com/submitform/",
                type : "POST", // https method
                data : new FormData(form),
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,

                // handle a successful response
                success : function(json) {
                    if(json['result'] == 'error'){
                        alert(json);
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('Submission successfull!');
                    }
                },

                // handle a non-successful response
                error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                    if(xhr.status == 0){
                        alert("We can't seem talk to the server.\nPlease reconnect and try again.");
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("Oops! We have encountered an error: " + xhr.status + "\nDetails: " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: try `window.onload = function() { getStuff('innerStuff');}`

Comment: @AndreiTodorut `getStuff()` works just fine. It's `submit_form()` that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the button cursor to pointer like this.

```
#submit-btn {cursor: pointer;}
```

Sounds weird I know but iOS has weird bugs with onClick();

Comment: Drop the javascript prefix and semicolon, its not necessary. so Javascript:onClick() should be onClick().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
<script>
getStuff = function(filename){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://website.com/ajax/",
        data: {
            'name': filename
        },
        success : function(data){
            $('#content-container').animate({opacity: '0'}, 250, function(){
    $('#content-container').html(data);
    /* Add this */
    var arr = $('#content-container')[0].getElementsByTagName('script')
    for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++)
    eval(arr[n].innerHTML)
   });
            $('#content-container').animate({opacity: '1'}, 250);
        }
    });
};

getStuff('innerStuff'); //Gets innerStuff.html
</script>
```

Comment: Using this, the iOS browsers don't load in the form at all. All I get instead is a blank space where the form used to be.